# Group by month and year from date field

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

From Data in the following Table **Loan_Amendment**:

```
    ID     |     Amount     | AddDeduct | AmendDate  
-----------+----------------+-----------+------------
 LT0000160 | 1000.000000000 | 2         | 2018-02-08
 LT0000170 | 1500.00000000  | 1         | 2018-02-10
 LN0000577 | 1000.000000000 | 1         | 2018-03-20
 LN0000587 | 2000.000000000 | 2         | 2018-03-20
```

I tried to select sum `Amount` field which have the same year and month of `AmendDate`.

Therefore, I tried select query in `SQLALchemy` as the following like this:

```
AmendObj = db.session.query(func.sum(Loan_Amendment.Amount).label('Amount'),
                            Loan_Amendment.AmendDate).\
    group_by(Loan_Amendment.AmendDate).\
    first()
```

However, from the above query I have tried I can only group by exact same date (year, month, and day) of `AmendDate`.

#### Updated:

My model look like below:

```
class Loan_Amendment(Object):
    ID              =   db.Column(db.String(13), primary_key=True)
    AddDeduct       =   db.Column(db.String(1))
    Amount          =   db.Column(db.Numeric(25, 9))
    AmendDate       =   db.Column(db.String(20))
```

Currently, I' using `Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.0` and `SQLAlchemy==0.9.9` and DB type is `postgresql`.

Which way I can select sum and group by only month and year from the `AmendDate`?

Comment: Which DB are you using?

Comment: I'm using `postgresql` DB. Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the [`date_trunc()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#id-1.5.8.14.5.2.2.9.1.1) function to truncate your dates to month precision:

```
month = func.date_trunc('month', Loan_Amendment.AmendDate)

AmendObj = db.session.query(func.sum(Loan_Amendment.Amount).label('Amount'),
                            month).\
    group_by(month).\
    first()
    # Did you mean all()?
```

Another option that's less DB dependent is to use [`EXTRACT()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#id-1.5.8.14.5.2.2.11.1.1):

```
from sqlalchemy import extract

AmendObj = db.session.query(func.sum(Loan_Amendment.Amount).label('Amount'),
                            extract('year', Loan_Amendment.AmendDate),
                            extract('month', Loan_Amendment.AmendDate)).\
    group_by(extract('year', Loan_Amendment.AmendDate),
             extract('month', Loan_Amendment.AmendDate)).\
    first()
```

---

Since your date columns are actually text, you need a cast first. If you're using a version of SQLAlchemy that has the [`ColumnElement.cast()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnElement.cast) shortcut, 1.0.7 or above, then just

```
func.date_trunc('month', Loan_Amendment.AmendDate.cast(Date))
```

but if not, then

```
from sqlalchemy import cast

func.date_trunc('month', cast(Loan_Amendment.AmendDate, Date))
```

Naturally the same applies if using EXTRACT.

---

A hacky solution given your model and data would be to simply take the substring that includes the year and month part and group by it:

```
month = func.substr(Loan_Amendment.AmendDate, 1, 7)
```

Comment: I followed above first option I got error message: `ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) function date_trunc(unknown, character varying) does not exist
   LINE 1: ...T sum("Loan_Amendment"."Amount") AS "Amount", date_trunc...
                                                                ^
   HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
    'SELECT sum("Loan_Amendment"."Amount") AS "Amount", date_trunc(%(date_trunc_2)s, "Loan_Amendment"."AmendDate") AS date_trunc_1...` I'm sure I already `from sqlalchemy import * Thanks.

Comment: From option 1, I tried to cast date to string like this `month = func.date_trunc('month', str(Loan_Amendment.AmendDate))` I got `ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) function date_trunc(unknown, unknown) is not unique`. what is wrong? Thanks.

Comment: You failed to mention that your date column is actually text. Add a cast **to** date: `Loan_Amendment.AmendDate.cast(Date)`. `str(Loan_Amendment.AmendDate)` is not a "cast to text". It simply produces the string representation of the given object *in Python*.

Comment: yes my date field is a text type. By casting, it like above `Loan_Amendment.AmendDate.cast(Date)`, it still error `AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with Loan_Amendment.AmendDate has an attribute 'cast'` :(

Comment: Please include what version of SQLAlchemy you are using and your actual models in the question. Meanwhile use the `sqlalchemy.sql.expression.cast()` construct to work around the error: `cast(Loan_Amendment.AmendDate, Date)`.

Comment: Please refer to my edited question, I include class model and version of sqlalchemy i'm using, Thanks.

Comment: I used `month = func.date_trunc('month', func.cast(MKT_LOAN_AMENDMENT.AmendDate,Date))` and it works very well now. :) Thanks very much for your help..